# IBM Mobile First 7.0 Persistent_Store_Failure

Tags: android, ubuntu, ibm-mobilefirst

I am tring to develop an offline hybrid application via IBM Mobile First 7.0. 
If I use 32bit Ubuntu 12.04 OS to build and deploy. I always get the same errors (see below) on Android 4.4.4 and 4.3 devices.

On the other hand if I build it on Mac (64bit / OSX Yosemite), the application works fine on the same device and same emulator. I could not find any solution, hope someone can see what I did not.

```
07-24 11:06:17.995: D/dalvikvm(2175): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3385K, 34% free 7986K/12080K, paused 4ms, total 7ms
07-24 11:06:18.059: E/JSONSTORE(2175): JSONStoreLogger.logError in JSONStoreLogger.java:189 :: Error validating schema
07-24 11:06:18.059: E/JSONSTORE(2175): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: STRİNG is not a constant in com.worklight.jsonstore.database.SearchFieldType
07-24 11:06:18.059: E/JSONSTORE(2175):  at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:198)
07-24 11:06:18.059: E/JSONSTORE(2175):  at com.worklight.jsonstore.database.SearchFieldType.valueOf(SearchFieldType.java:14)
07-24 11:06:18.059: E/JSONSTORE(2175):  at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.ProvisionActionDispatcher.parseSearchFields(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:94)
07-24 11:06:18.059: E/JSONSTORE(2175):  at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.ProvisionActionDispatcher.createCollectionInstance(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:64)
07-24 11:06:18.059: E/JSONSTORE(2175):  at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.ProvisionActionDispatcher.databaseActionDispatch(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:125)
07-24 11:06:18.059: E/JSONSTORE(2175):  at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.BaseDatabaseActionDispatcher.actionDispatch(BaseDatabaseActionDispatcher.java:36)
07-24 11:06:18.059: E/JSONSTORE(2175):  at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.BaseActionDispatcher.dispatch(BaseActionDispatcher.java:90)
07-24 11:06:18.059: E/JSONSTORE(2175):  at com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.DispatchingPlugin$ActionDispatcherRunnable.run(DispatchingPlugin.java:79)
07-24 11:06:18.059: E/JSONSTORE(2175):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-24 11:06:18.059: E/JSONSTORE(2175):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-24 11:06:18.059: E/JSONSTORE(2175):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-24 11:06:18.067: I/NONE(2175): PERSISTENT_STORE_FAILURE
07-24 11:06:18.083: E/wl.jsonstore(2175): {"src":"initCollection","err":-1,"msg":"PERSISTENT_STORE_FAILURE","col":"people","usr":"jsonstore","doc":{},"res":{}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug. You should never get exceptions like that.

Please open an IBM PMR (support ticket) so that the development team will investigate this, and if indeed found as a defect, provide a fix.

I do suggest though that you will edit the question with the complete code that you have used in the app when using JSONStore.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually we found the reason of the bug which is about the language of the device. Our customers use 'Turkish' so as you can see in the error log above, somehow MFP converts 'string' to 'STRİNG'. We are planning to open an IBM PMR for this but if you can suggest a quick workaround , I would appreciate.

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ***STRİNG*** is not a constant in     com.worklight.jsonstore.database.SearchFieldType
```